# Meromorphic functions in projective space

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-space, complex-manifolds, meromorphic-functions, holomorphic-bundles

It is well known that meromorphic functions in $\mathbb P^n_\mathbb C$ are of the form $p/q$ where $p$, $q$ are homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb C[x_0 , \ldots , x_n]$ of the same degree, and $q \neq 0$. For example [here](https://planetmath.org/meromorphicfunctiononprojectivespacemustberational#:%7E:text=To%20define%20a%20rational%20function,meromorphic%20function%20on%20Pn.&text=In%20fact%2C%20every%20meromorphic%20function%20on%20Pn%20is%20rational.) it is shown using Chow's theorem that subvarieties of $\mathbb P^n_\mathbb C$ are algebraic.

However, reading the book Complex geometry: An introduction by D. Huybrechts, Problem 2.1.3 asks to find the *algebraic dimension* $a(\mathbb P^n)$ of $\mathbb P^n$, which is the transcendence degree of the field of meromorphic functions. At this point in the book, only the local theory of holomorphic functions and the definitions of complex manifolds have been carried put, so I am wondering if there is an elementary proof of this (ie, that the $a(\mathbb P^n)=n$), since Chow's theorem is very deep.

By elementary I mean, using basically the local Theorey of holomorphic functions in $\mathbb C^n$ ie Hartogs' Theorem, Weierstrass prparation and its corollaries, Riemann extension theorem and the Nullstellensatz.

It is clear that in order to get $a(\mathbb P^n)=n$ it is enough to show that the meromorphic functions are rational, as explained in the comments. I would imagine this can be done using line bundles, the fact that any line bundle in $\mathbb P^n$ is $\mathcal O(d)$ and that sections of that line bundle are polynomials of degree $d$. This approach uses Hartogs' Theorem. However, it uses material which is much more advanced in the book but it hints to me that one can try to use Hartogs' Theorem to give the elementary proof I am looking for.

**EDIT**: An answer should by an elementary proof of one of the two facts: $\mathbb P^n$ has algebraic dimension $n$ or all meromorphic functions in $\mathbb P^n$ are quotients of polynomials of the same degree.

Comment: If you can use some algebraic geometry, this is a standard fact. The algebraic function field of $\mathbb P^N$ is the same as the field of merom. functions you just described. Now the inclusion $\mathbb A^N \to \mathbb P^N$ is a birational map, and birational varieties have isomorphic algebraic function fields. But the field of functions of $\mathbb A^N$ is $\mathbb C(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$.

This is how I would argue, assuming some algebraic geometry. Now a direct proof (using just algebraic stuff) or a complex-geometric one I honestly don't know. Hope it helps (knowing that probably it wont).

Comment: @fbianchini I was aware that this is standard using algebraic geometry, but the fact that meromorphic functions are the same as algebraic ones is part of GAGA, which is non-trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you are looking for. You want a elementary proof that the field of meromorphic functions of $\mathbb P^N$ is the one you described, right? I thought you wanted an elementary proof that the transcendence degree is $N$.

Comment: @fbianchini a proof of any of the two facts suffices me. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, great. Well, I can help you with the algebraic dimension. Supposing we already know the merom. functions in $\mathbb P^N$ is $S(x_0, \ldots, x_N)$ (field given by fractions of homog. pol. with same degree), define the ring homomorphism $p/q \mapsto p(1, x_1, \ldots, x_N)/ q(1, x_1, \ldots, x_N)$ to $\mathbb C(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$. This is injective since both are fields and is surjective because given two pol. $f,g$, if $d = \deg f - \deg g$, then the quotient $x_0^{-d} \frac{ x_0^{\deg f} f(x_1/x_0, \ldots, x_N/x_0)}{ x_0^{\deg g} g(x_1/x_0, \ldots, x_N/x_0)}$ maps to $f/g$. So it is an iso

Comment: Just for the sake of completion: Now we know that the field of merom. functions of $\mathbb P^N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$ and this has trivially transcendence degree $N$.

Comment: @fbianchini yes, that argument is what I was refering to with the line "It is clear that it is enough to show that the meromorphic functions are rational"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to prove the statement without explicitly computing the field of meromorphic functions of $\mathbb{P}^n$:

Every ratio of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree in $\mathbb{C}[z_0, \ldots, z_n]$ defines a meromorphic function of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (you can show this with elementary methods from Chapter 2.1). Therefore $S(z_0, \ldots, z_n) \cong \mathbb{C}(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ is a subfield of $K(\mathbb{P}^n)$. We know that $\mathbb{C}(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ has transcendence degree $n$, so $a(\mathbb{P}^n) \geq n$. By Proposition 2.1.9 (Siegel), we have that $a(\mathbb{P}^n) \leq n$. Thus, $a(\mathbb{P}^n) = n$.

Comment: Nice, I guess this proves that meromorphic functions are an algebraic extension of rational ones and then the hard part is to show equality